# chip navigation bar animation not works

Tags: java, android, animation, uinavigationbar, android-bottomappbar

i used this GitHub library in my code for bottom navigation.[chip navigation bar](https://github.com/ismaeldivita/chip-navigation-bar/)
i tried to make it floating up after starting the program.but when run the program it is disappeared but when clicking in the buttons place . on click listener works but i couldn't see the navigation bar 
this is the click listener ;

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btmNav = findViewById(R.id.btmNav);
    layout = findViewById(R.id.cntBTM);
    animMove = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_up);
    btmNav.startAnimation(animMove);

    //////////////*


    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        NewsFragment newsFragment = new NewsFragment();

        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, newsFragment)
                .commit();

    }


    btmNav.setOnItemSelectedListener(new ChipNavigationBar.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(int id) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            switch (id) {
                case R.id.home:
                    fragment = new WebFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.activity:
                    fragment = new ActivityFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.settings:
                    fragment = new SettingFragment();
                    break;
            }
            if (fragment != null) {
                fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
                        .commit();
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error in creating fragment");
            }
        }
    });
```

and this in main activity

```
 <com.ismaeldivita.chipnavigation.ChipNavigationBar
    android:id="@+id/btmNav"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:cnb_menuResource="@menu/bottom_menu"
    app:cnb_unselectedColor="#fff"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this library https://github.com/ismaeldivita/chip-navigation-bar

Dont forget to add maven in settings.graddle

```
maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
```

And dont forget to add this dependency to your build.graddle file

```
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.6.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

add your `build.gradle` `implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.72'`

Comment: I added it previously.

Answer (score 0):

add this/ maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' } in dependencyResolutionManagement

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).